# one method calling another forever, will this cause any problems?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, uiviewanimation

I have written a little customer survey application and at the top I have an image of a car and a van that i pretend are zooming round. But the way I have coded it turns it into an infinate loop where one method calls the other and vice versa.. this is so the animation plays for ever.

here is my code

```
-(void)doAnimate {

    // animate van
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:7.f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         vanView.frame = CGRectMake(770, 175, vanView.frame.size.width, vanView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             [self doAnimateLoop];
                         }
                     }];

    // animate car
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:3.f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         carView.frame = CGRectMake(-600, 250, carView.frame.size.width, carView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                         }
                     }];
}

-(void)doAnimateLoop {


    vanView.frame = CGRectMake(-600, 175, vanView.frame.size.width, vanView.frame.size.height);
    carView.frame = CGRectMake(770, 250, carView.frame.size.width, carView.frame.size.height);


    // second animation van
    // animate van
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:2.f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         vanView.frame = CGRectMake(111, 175, vanView.frame.size.width, vanView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {

                         }
                     }];

    // animate car
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:5.f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         carView.frame = CGRectMake(104, 250, carView.frame.size.width, carView.frame.size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             [self doAnimate];
                         }
                     }];

}
```

I would like to know if this is going to cause any issues with the app in the future? like memory leak or something that could cause it to crash.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops are not necessarily bad, if you take care.

You need to make sure you stop the animation when it is not needed as it will take up precious CPU time. This can make you app slow to respond since it is spending CPU time animating when it doesn't need to.

You can stop the animation when the view is no longer attached to an active window (see code below), which is the case when you navigate away from the view controller.

```
/**
 * doAnimate
 * Animates view with a call back to its self for infinite animation, stops on view unload.
 */
-(void)doAnimate
{
    //view is active, animate. else stop
    //this will stop the animation when the view is unloaded
    if (self.view.window)
    {
        //Animate your views
    }
}
```

As per memory leaks if you have good coding standards and practices memory leaks are rare. If you are concerned or suspect a memory leak then you can use the usually tools (i.e [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)) to inspect for memory usage.

As per your code it looks fine for a basic implementation.
Good Luck.

Answer (score -2):

Writhing into an infinite loop is not the problem if it is running in a separate thread. The question is can you handle the memory. as the loops are infinite even the tiniest leak will result in a crash. I would suggest you to use some api's that does this effectively and leave it in its hands if you suspect your hands are dirty